# How to play youtube videos through vlc plugin?

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I'm using vlc plugin into C# Windows form application. It works fine with all media type but it can't play youtube videos through the plugin also it can be played in the main player itself. I'm using the following code :

```
    axVLCPlugin2.playlist.add("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxPtmLmqdXU");
    axVLCPlugin2.playlist.play();
```

How the could should be to be able to play youtube videos ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying the URL of the youtube web page, not of the video itself. You need to get the URL of the video itself and specify that. There are many web pages that allow you to extract the URL of the video, given a youtube page URL, like:

[Get link to actual video](http://www.vidimonkey.uni.cc/)

Comment: Thanx Michel, but i tried to use the actual download link in the plugin but it didn't work too.it looked like this"http://v19.nonxt2.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?ip=0.0.0.0&sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Calgorithm%2Cburst%2Cfactor%2Coc%3AU0dXTFJNUV9FSkNNN19KR1VD&fexp=905303&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=34&ipbits=0&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1287223200&key=yt1&signature=5DD0E7238F0CC277693BE72551449ECA0119996B.1DA3D2FCC381A8E8F713999D111041EA6DFAA491&factor=1.25&id=85f192f2827d34f7&redirect_counter=1"

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason why this won't work. EgyEast, please post your exact steps if it didn't work.